# The Class Which implements Serializable needs to impliment some methods?

Tags: java, serialization, serializable

I know that Serializable is a marker interface. Then what the below method signatures mean?

```
 private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out)
     throws IOException
 private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
     throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;
 private void readObjectNoData() 
     throws ObjectStreamException;
```

This is from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

and in the page it's written as "Classes that require special handling during the serialization and deserialization process must implement special methods with these exact signatures: "

I'm confused. Whether Serializable is a marker interface?

Comment: And they are private as well! O_o

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Serializable is a marker interface. Only classes that require special handling must implement these methods.

Put differently, you *can* implement one or more of those methods to customize how instances of the class are serialized or deserialized. This is usually not needed, as the default behavior is aedequate for most needs.

Answer (score 1):

Those methods are used to customize the serialization process. I will give you an example.

```
class Person implements java.io.Serializable {

int id;
String name;
String city;

Person(int id, String name, String city) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
this.city = city;
}

private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream stream)
        throws IOException {
    stream.writeInt("ID : " + id);
    stream.writeObject("Name : " + name);
    stream.writeObject("City : " + city);
}

private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream stream)
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    id = stream.readInt();
    name = (String) stream.readObject();
    city = (String) stream.readObject();
}

public String toString() {
    return id + "\t" + name + "\t" + city + "\t";
}
}
```

Note that the serialization is customized by using those methods. I have added string constants in writeObject method when serializing fields which the default serialization method won't do.

Answer (score 0):

I'll throw a wild guess here on the reason why. Given the fact that you can use tags to determine which fields are serializable, my first thought is that the inner workings of the serialization, for example in the `ObjectOutputStream`, are done through reflection.

So maybe the `writeObject` method is actually also checking if there is a private method with the same signature defined on the object and call that one if it is. In the end, that same method is already using reflection possible to determine which field to serialize and how, so also checking the existence of a special method is not a massive overhead I believe...

It may seem a bit strange but sounds like a decent solution. Forcing implementation in the interface would have been too much, since most of the time is the common one. Using an abstract class would have not been possible in a Singe Inheritance Model like Java. C# uses attributes (the equivalent of `@` annotations in Java).

Hope someone with more knowledge can shed more light on this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Its simple. If you want custom serialzation, you provide the above mentioned methods by you in the class which is to be serialied.

Example: If you're seriailizing User.java provide the following methods in this class for custom serialization:
 private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out)
     throws IOException
 private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
     throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;

Anyhow when you call the serialzation of the object through, objectOutputStream.writeObject (Object which is in this case is User), control will be automatically redirected to writeObject method of User.java.

If you dont provide the methods in User.java. Then the process goes default way.

Note: if you provide implementation of writeObject/readObject both in the class to be serialized, then only custom serialzation works otherwise it takes the default route.
Hope this helps!